# Python Question: For some reason my list is out of index even though their are enough arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, indexing

```
def nterm_calculator(*n):
   print("Please input the numbers that you want the bot to calculate")

   sequence = [n]

   difference = sequence[1] - sequence[0]
   diference_2 = sequence[2] - sequence[1]

   if difference == difference_2:
       ultimate_difference = difference * 1
   elif difference != difference_2:
       ultimate_difference = False
       print('Error: This sequence is not compatible with this function')
   

   nterm = ultimate_difference * 'n'


#main
def main():
   nterm_calculator( 1, 3, 5, 7)

main()
```

for some reason, I keep getting an index error like this. **I'm new to programming and python so help will be very much appreciated** It's probably something simple

```
 File "C:\Users\Faz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\algorithm practise - finding the nth term of a linear sequence.py", line 15, in nterm_calculator
    difference = sequence[1] - sequence[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: @Mustafa Thank you very much this was very useful in helping me finish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `def f(*n)` syntax, all the positional arguments passed to function will be gathered into a tuple named `n`. In your case it will be

```
n = (1, 3, 5, 7)
```

But then you're doing `[n]` which makes a list with 1 element which is the tuple above, i.e.,

```
[(1, 3, 5, 7)]
```

Since this has 1 element, any index bigger than 0 will give error.

Some remedies are:

```
# with list constructor
sequence = list(n)
```

or

```
# with unpacking
sequence = [*n]
```

or better yet you don't need to cast this to a list given your code. A tuple might be enough since e.g., you don't attempt to modify it at all and both are [sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) so e.g., indexing is supported. So you can either do `sequence = n` but better yet you can directly use `n` wherever you write `sequence` (you can change the function signature to

```
def nterm_calculator(*sequence):
```